# How to use gitlab artifacts from the same pipeline, which has been run earlier?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In gitlab I have the following configuration:

```yaml
job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "run3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - echo "Job stage1 updating file dates.txt"
    - date >> data/dates.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - data/dates.txt


job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "run3"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - echo "Job stage2 updating file uptime.txt"
    - uptime >> data/uptime.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - data/uptime.txt


job3:
  stage: stage3
  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "run3"
      when: always
  script:
    - echo "Running stage 3"
    - cat data/dates.txt
    - cat data/uptime.txt
  needs:
    - job: job1
      artifacts: true
    - job: job2
      artifacts: true
```

At a given time, I run the pipeline and the jobs `job1` and `job2` are run and they create artifacts. (The above is just an **example**. In reality these jobs are much more time consuming. It is just an example...)

At some later time I want to run just the job `job3` which should use the available artifacts that has been generated by the other two pipelines earlier.

However, when I run the `job3`-only pipeline I get an error

```
'job3' job needs 'job1' job, but 'job1' is not in any previous stage 'job3' job needs 'job2' job, but 'job2' is not in any previous stage
```

But I can go myself to the latest `job1` and `job2` via the UI and download the created artifact myself.

How can I do the same in `job3`, if that is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a little misunderstanding - pipeline artifacts are only available within the same pipeline. If you want to persist them or use them for a late stage, you need to either store them in the package registry and fetch them from there or fetch them via api from the previous job runs.

... but i think for your use case there is an easier solution

```yaml
job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules:
    - when: always
  script:
    - echo "Job stage1 updating file dates.txt"
    - date >> data/dates.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - data/dates.txt


job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - when: always
  script:
    - echo "Job stage2 updating file uptime.txt"
    - uptime >> data/uptime.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - data/uptime.txt

    
job3:
  stage: stage3
  rules:
    - when: manual
      allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "Running stage 3"
    - cat data/dates.txt
    - cat data/uptime.txt
  needs:
    - job: job1
      artifacts: true
    - job: job2
      artifacts: true
```

you can set the execution to `manual` and `allow _failure` for the third stage. With this, each pipeline will have a manual step, which you can trigger by clicking. Furthermore with `allow_failure` it will also not block the pipeline from finishing. So each time your pipeline is triggered, you can manually choose if it should run job3 or not.

Comment: I want to trigger job3 also automatically by a schedule

Comment: the question is, why does it have to be timely separated. it looks like you try to mimic jenkins behaviour, which is supoptimal when working with gitlab ci. I would suggest you also outline the approach/your need which you try to solve, aka the overall problem, without specifics to the job. there are ways to handle such behaviour - but normally you chose to have one pipeline doing everything together, as you do have the safety that the artifacts and everything is actually from the same commit. furthermore with environments you gain more security for your deployments etc.

Comment: I actually do not care about the commit. The pipeline itself has nothing to do with the code.  The pipeline is being used to create a file containing results about OTHER repositories etc. which is very time consuming and uses a LOT of API calls. 

In order to have a weekly status update of what has changes in these repos I just want to "store/save" these results weekly, without rerunning the extensive pipeline (which would result in exact the same data artifacts). I just want to re-use the data artifacts that have already been generated in a previous run of the pipeline, maybe 3 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, automatic artifact restoration only propagates within a single pipeline (or parent-child pipeline chains).

If you want to use artifacts from an earlier pipeline, the provided method is to use the [artifacts API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html). It even allows you to use this endpoint with the builtin `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to authenticate and download artifacts within the same project.

This is useful, for example, when you always want the artifact from a particular ref (like main/master). However, if may be difficult to identify exactly which ref/artifact you're looking for. You might consider using `cahce:` with a proper `key:` to store the ref your subsequent pipelines should use with the artifacts API -- that is since caches, unlike artifacts, do persist across pipelines.

Given that caches do persist across pipelines (with proper `key:`), you may also consider them for your use case altogether. However, you should treat caches as ephemeral and have a strategy for what to do if the cache disappears (as the cache can be cleared by users or without warning).

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove needs:
2. Consider using cache: instead.
3. If cache does not meet your requirements, you can use the api in job3 to reach back and get the artifacts from a completed pipeline.
4. If that doesn’t work, consider using the generic package registry.
5. Consider running job1 & 2 when you need to run 3.

Comment: The cache idea does not seem to work (or I am using it in the wrong way)